# Do Jews believe in exorcism and what is the biblical basis for it?

Tags: chinuch-education, judaism

Roman Catholic and Orthodox Christians believe in exorcisms (ie the religious or spiritual practice of evicting demons, jinns, or other malevolent spiritual entities from a person) but does the Jewish faith believe in exorcism  and what is the basis from the Torah that these teachings are biblical?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Dybbuk-Gershon-Winkler/dp/091081838X/ref=sr_1_5?crid=Z4JQLO0KNKSD&keywords=dybbuk+book&qid=1670197946&sprefix=dybbu%2Caps%2C467&sr=8-5

Comment: Consider Samuel 1:16:

Comment: Read Talmud Pesachim 110 and on, it discusses at length demons and whatnot and how to let’s say be safe from them in the nighttime. Sorta related to exorcisms

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dybbuk

Comment: Why does this have the tag "chinuch-education"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, read the [final chapter (40)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_HaGilgulim.40.24?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) of Shaar HaGilgulim (Gates of Reincarnation) by Rav Chaim Vital, the student of the greatest kabbalist of Jewish history, the Arizal. Nevertheless, the way of Jews is different to that of gentiles.

> ואחר כך יאמר י"ג מדות של מיכה הנביא מי אל כמוך וכו'. ואח"כ יאמר פסוק
> דברי עונות גברו מני וגו'. ופסוק אשרי תבחר ותקרב ישכון חצירך וגו'.
> ופסוק וירדו כל עבדיך אלה אלי וגו'. ויאמר פסוק זה ג"פ. ואח"כ יאמר צא צא
> צא. ויכוין הכונות אשר בפסוק זה ככתוב אצלי. ותכף בהיותו מסיים מלת צא
> ג"פ, הקים רגל השמאלית של הנערה למעלה בפני כל העם, ויצא מאצבע קטנה של
> רגלה, וצעק בקול גדול, ואמר עליכם שלום ג"פ, והשבתי לו לך לשלום, לך
> לשלום ג"פ. ותכף ומיד ישבה הנערה, ופתחה עיניה והביטה בי, ונתביישה ממני,
> ואמרה מה אלו האנשים עושים, כי לא ידעה מאומה מכל מה שעשינו, ונשקה ידי
> ואכלה ושתה

Here is a quote in English from that work,

"I found her in a state of being possessed, but I was unsure if it was [because of] a damager, a demon, or an evil Jewish spirit."

A gentile judge trapped the gentile damager spirit that had entered her due to desire for her in a bottle which was buried as is a custom of the gentiles. Regarding the Jewish spirit, he describes the passages from the Torah and Tehillim which were used to free the Jewish soul trapped in her to go to gehinnom and be healed after these many passages and intentions including the quoting of the shema by the soul it concludes that a phrase including the world leave was recited three times:

"Immediately upon the word "Leave" the third time, the girl's left leg became elevated before everyone, and it kept from the baby toe of her foot. It yelled out loud and said, "Peace upon you!" three times, and I answered it, "Go in peace! Go in peace!" three times.

Immediately the girl regained consciousness, sat up, and opened her eyes and looked at me. She became embarrassed before me and asked, "Who are all these people?" having no knowledge whatsoever of anything that we did. She kissed my hand, ate and drank.

This I did on the fifth day of the week, on the 26th day of Tammuz, in the year 5426 from Creation, in Egypt, G-d should protect us. I have written all this for those who come after me, so that they should know that G-d is among the Jewish people. The young Shmuel Vital."

Comment: Welcome, CP and thanks for the answer. It would probably enhance your answer if you have a link to the source for the quotation you included or relevant passage in Shaar HaGilgulim.

Comment: @NJM You added a broken link.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you - the link should be good now.